# How can I change the default Gmail return address?

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, when I compose an email, it defaults to using my Gmail address as the return address.

Is there a way to change it such that the default return address is one of my other return addresses registered with Gmail, so that I don't have to manually do this on each new composed email?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to *Setting* at the top of the Gmail screen then click **Accounts and Imports**.

The second set of options/settings is *Send mail as:* where you should see the accounts you have linked and are available. Click the link **make default** next to the other email address you want to use (your Gmail account should currently show *default* where the link would normally be).

Comment: When I do this, replies to my message go to the external mail (which in my case is then forwarded back to my gmail.)

Comment: Right, that is what I am doing too.

Comment: Digging even deeper. In the same area I mention before you can click "edit info" for your gmail account which will open a new window. Here there is an option to "Specify a different reply-to address." This will let you send replies "as" your gmail address but replies will go to whatever you specify here.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and didn't find the functionality you want. It sounds like you'll need to use (OS X) Mail or Outlook to manage the multiple accounts like you describe.

Or you could go to Settings > Forwarding and just forward from this first account to the desired one. That way you only have to check one spot too.